# DirectX vs FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, directx, decode, h.264, h.265

i'm in the process of deciding how to decode received video frames, based on the following:

1. platform is Windows.
2. frames are encoded in H264 or H265.
3. GPU should be used as much
4. certainly we prefer less coding and simplest code. we just need to decode and show the result on screen. no recording is required, not anything else.

still i'm a newbie, but i think one may decode a frame directly by directx or through ffmpeg. am i right?
if so, which one is preferred?

Comment: directx is a graphical rendering API, it does not decode video

Comment: are you sure? the new version of directx is coming with name media foundation

Comment: To VTT, the interface to decode video using GPU is called IDirectXVideoDecoder, part of MediaFoundation API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple approach and simple code using GPU only, take a look at my project using DirectX : [H264Dxva2Decoder](https://github.com/mofo7777/H264Dxva2Decoder)

If you are ready to code, you can use my approach.

If not, you can use MediaFoundation or FFMPEG, both can do the job.

MediaFoundation is C++ and COM oriented. FFMPEG is C oriented. It can make the difference for you.

**EDIT**

You can use my program because you have frames encoded in H264 or H265. For h265, you will have to add extra code.

Of course, you need to make modifications. And yes you can send frames to DirectX without using a file. This project use only avcc video file format, but it can be modify for others cases.

You don't need the atom parser. You need  to modify the nalu parser, if frames are annex-b format, for example. You will also need to modify the buffering mechanism, if frames are annex-b format.

I can help you, if you provide frames samples encoded in H264.

About Ffmpeg, it has fewer limitations than my program, according to h264 specifications,
but does not provide the rendering mechanism. You will have to mix Ffmepg and my rendering mechanism, for example.

Or study a program like MPC-HC that shows the mix. I can not help anymore here.

**EDIT 2**

One thing to know, you can't decode encoded packets directly to GPU. You need to parse them before. That's why there is a nalu parser (see DXVA_PicParams_H264).

If you are not ready to code and to understand how it works, use Ffmpeg, it will be simpler, in effect. You can focus on rendering, not on decoding.

> It's also important to know which one gives a better result, consumes less resources (CPU, GPU, RAM (both system memory and graphics card memory), supports wider range of formats, etc.

You ask for a real expertise...

If you code your own program, you will be able to optimize it, and certainly get better results. If you use Ffmpeg, and it has performance problems in your context, you could be blocked... because you will not modify Ffmpeg.

You say you will use Bosch cameras. Normally, all encoded video will be in the same format. So once your code is able to decode it, you don't really need all the Ffmpeg features.

Comment: I downloaded and could build the project. But when I run it, I get no result. The program terminates just after execution.

Comment: I could run it at last. Maybe the cause was my video file. It's a very good sample for beginning. But before beginning, let me know whether I may send frames to directx instead of introducing the file for it. If it's impossible to give frames instead of the whole file to directx, I need to use ffmpeg instead. In the sample hw_decode.c, how can I show the decoded frame on screen?

Comment: Your code works great, but seems to be too complex for me as someone who has never decoded by hardware nor rendered directly on graphics card memory. Now I should decide which one of the ways to follow; directx or ffmpeg. As you mentioned, any change in source video will affect on my code directly and i should prepare my code for it, while in ffmpeg, it seems that it may handle a wide variety of the formats. My code may not need so many changes if the input format will change from h264 to h265. So it seems that beginning with ffmpeg makes my code simpler. Am i right?

Comment: If I'm right, I should extract some parts of your code which renders the frame. This is not simple, because I should understand your code first. I don't know whether it's possible to render what MF has not decoded itself on screen (by screen I mean hw surface). How can i mix them? I found that the maximum surfaces available by directx is 32. Am I right? If so, how can I show a matrix of 8x8 cameras? You asked about the input format. We (our customers) use a wide variety of Bosch cameras, mostly H264 and MJPEG. This may include H265 in the future. But we can't limit on it too.

Comment: It's also important to know which one gives a better result, consumes less resources (CPU, GPU, RAM (both system memory and graphics card memory), supports wider range of formats, etc. Is ffmpeg with dxva2 just a wrapper on directx which makes coding simpler? I need to know many things about these two contexts. But if I want to go through a short way, which one is preferred? I gave an mp4 file to your sample code and it didn't accept it. So I had to download from the url you introduced. While hw_deocde could decode it. It seems that directx is more sensitive to the input file format...

Comment: Note that I prefer not to involve system memory for this purpose. I prefer to just hold the encoded packets in system memory. Then I decode them directly to GPU and render them on screen without need to copy from system memory to graphics card memory.

Comment: "I gave an mp4 file to your sample code and it didn't accept it."

Could you share this file, so i could see what's going on ?

Comment: oh! sorry. I found that was my mistake. I thought giving my video file name as an argument to the program prioritize the built-in name. It works.

Comment: Please let's go on with the other things I said above.

Comment: Thanks mofo77 for your comments. After reading your recommendations, I decided to use ffmpeg to focus on rendering and have a library on hand to rely decoding on it. This enables me to forget thinking about how to decode and what formats the input source may have. Now, please let me know, how can I use GPU for rendering the decoded frame. In hw_decode.c sample, I see that DXVA2 may be used for decoding, but it includes no rendering method. If the decoded frame is now on the graphics card memory, I prefer it to remain there and just be rendered. What's your suggestion?

Comment: that's another question. Like i said, look at MPC-BE source code. They do it for h264/mpeg2/wmv : https://sourceforge.net/p/mpcbe/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/filters/transform/MPCVideoDec/